# Using Android's New Photo Picker Combined with Camera Option?

Tags: android

Has anyone found a good way to implement Android's new [Photo Picker](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/photopicker) with an option to also take a photo using the camera?

My app currently has a chooser that lets users add a photo from existing or take a new one with the camera by combining two intents:

```
// Create intent to select existing photo
final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);

// Create an intent for the chooser starting with the Gallery intent
final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent,
        getResources().getString(R.string.select_source));

// Then add the Camera options to the intent
chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[cameraIntents.size()]));
startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, SELECT_PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE);
```

The new Photo Picker does not create an intent, so I can't use my existing method of providing a similar option.

I've considered showing a dialog box with two options and linking each from there, but would prefer something similar to what I have now.